# Style is being added to the last child among a set of elements, instead of the last child of the selected element

Tags: javascript, css

```js
var NavLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');
var circuses = document.querySelectorAll('.circle');


for (var i = 0; i < NavLinks.length; i++) {
    var navLink = NavLinks[i];
    navLink.addEventListener('click', function () {      
        for (var i = 0; i < circuses.length; i++) {
           var circle = circuses[i];
           circle.style.display='none';
        }
        var theLastChild = navLink.lastChild;
        theLastChild.style.display='block';   
      
    }
    );  
  }
```

```css
.nav-container{   
    height: 10px;
    background: white;
    padding: 30px 0px 40px 0px;  
    margin-left: 18%;
    margin-right: 18%;     
}
.nav-body  ul{
    text-align: right;
}
.nav-body  ul li{
    display: inline- block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 30px;    
}
#logo{
    margin-right: 0px;
}
.nav-body ul li{
    line-height: 0.6;
}
#logo{    
    margin-top: -10px;
} 
#logo-light-blue{
    color: #5dc5ef;
    font-weight: 900;
}
#logo-dark-blue{
    color: #1885c8;
    font-weight: 900;
}
.circle {
    display: none;
 width: 8px;
 height: 8px;
 background: #5dc5ef;
 /* -moz-border-radius: 50px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 50px; */
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<header class="nav-container">
        <nav class="nav-body">
            <ul>
                <li class="nav-link"><a  href="#">צור קשר</a>
                <div class="circle"></div></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">המלצות ומאמרים</a>
                    <div class="circle"></div></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">שאלות נפוצות</a>
                    <div class="circle"></div></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">אודות ד"ר שי מרון אלדר</a>
                    <div class="circle"></div></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">אודות ההליכים</a>
                    <div class="circle"></div></li>
                <li class="nav-link"><a href="#">ראשי</a>
                    <div class="circle"></div></li>
                <li id="logo"> <h3> <span id="logo-light-blue">  ד"ר </span><span id="logo-dark-blue"> שי מרון  אלדר  </span></h3><br>   
                        <h6> פתרונות כירורגיים להשמנת יתר וניתוחים זעיר פולשניים</h6></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

I need to make a blue circle under that category menu, which I pressed. But now blue circle added only to last menu category. Doesn't matter which one was pressed.
I looking for the last child of that menu category which was pressed. But it shows me every time last child of all menu categories.
What is wrong?

>

Comment: The ID attribute should be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have errors in HTML. Span tags need to be closed.

```
            <li id="logo"> 
              <h3> 
                <span id="logo-light-blue">  ד"ר </span>
                <span id="logo-dark-blue"> שי מרון  אלדר  </span>
              </h3>
              <br>   
              <h6> פתרונות כירורגיים להשמנת יתר וניתוחים זעיר פולשניים</h6>
             </li>
```

And Id attributes should be unique to the element, you are repeating the circle as an Id all over the place.

```
<div id="circle"></div></li>
```

It this doesn't solve it, try explaining the question better since even in the demo you have put result is all over the place. Are we missing some CSS or a style lib?

EDIT: I think I know what you wanna, is it this? Have a look at fiddle:
[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/1j6hfkxp/)

Do you need circle removed from other elements once you click your element?

If you need the circle to be only on 1 element, it needs to be removed from others.
Here is a fiddle showing that:
[fiddle with only 1 circle](https://jsfiddle.net/ewqwvbpq/)

Difference is in:

```
var NavLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');

for (var i = 0; i < NavLinks.length; i++) {
    var navLink = NavLinks[i];
    navLink.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
            var allNavs = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link div');
        for (var it = 0; it < allNavs.length; it++){
            console.log(allNavs[it]);
          allNavs[it].classList.add('invisible');
          allNavs[it].classList.remove('circleVisible');
         }
        console.log(allNavs);
            var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;
        var circleDiv = targetElement.parentNode.querySelectorAll('div');
        console.log(circleDiv[0]);
        circleDiv[0].classList.add('circleVisible');
        circleDiv[0].classList.remove('invisible');
        console.log(circleDiv[0]);
    }
    );  
  }
```

I have left console.logs, so you see how it works, remove them when running the code for real :)

Comment: Yes, I change Id on class. It didn't help. it is not full css. Full is too long. This css only for a footer.  The question is how to make a blue circle under that menu category, on which I pressed, not under last one.

Comment: I updated the answer. HTML and JS have been reworked, I have removed excess CSS but feel free to only copy HTML and JS. If you need circle removed from other elements once you click a new one I can add that too.

Comment: Thank you so much! You help me to solve this problem in such a smart way. First, you indicated category which was clicked. And after circle! It was a problem with code - I didn't   indicate the category.

Answer (score 0):

The first big problem I see is you have nested for loops but are using the same iterator variable of *i*. If you are going to next the loops, you need the inner loop to have a different variable. In situations like this, I will often use *ii* just because it's easy.

Furthermore, you seem to be doing this in a roundabout way. I'm not entirely sure what you need, but if it is as it appears, then this solution is simpler.

CSS

```
.circle {
    display: none;
    ... other attributes
}

.active-menu-item > .circle {
    display: block;
}
```

JavaScript

```
var NavLinks = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-link');

for (var i = 0; i < NavLinks.length; i++) {
    var navLink = NavLinks[i];
    navLink.addEventListener('click', function () {      
        for (var ii = 0; ii < NavLinks.length; ii++) {
           NavLinks[ii].classList.remove("active-menu-item");
        }
        navLink.classList.add("active-menu-item");
    });  
}
```